# Sparse DataFrame returns AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have created the following DataFrame:

```
trains = np.arange(100)
tresholds = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
tuples = []
for i in trains:
    for j in tresholds:
        tuples.append((i, j))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['trains', 'tresholds'])
matrix = np.empty((len(index), len(trains)))
matrix.fill(np.nan)
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=index, columns=trains, dtype=float)
```

This DataFrame is filled using `df.loc[(x, y), z]` indexing, but it contains more `NaN` than actual numbers, so I wanted to create a Sparse DataFrame. But `df.to_sparse()` gives me [this error (full trace)](http://pastebin.com/STkt5QeJ).

Comment: It looks like a problem in the attempt to pretty print the result, what version ipython, pandas are you using? If you ran your code outside of ipython does it work?

Comment: When running outside of iPython (just python in the terminal), it gives me an error from somewhere in the pandas library.

Comment: I'm running Pandas 0.15.2 and IPython 3.0.0

Comment: Could you try upgrading to pandas 0.16.0 to see if this resolves your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example code to reproduce the problem, thanks

Comment: I've edited my code so it build an empty DataFrame. This can just be filled with some random values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nan columns are buggy ATM in this kind of conversion. If you already had a `SparseFrame` adding a nan column would work however.

If you did this:

```
df.iloc[0] = 0
df.to_sparse()
```

works.

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10079; Would love to have pull-requests from people interested in improving sparse!.

Comment: So basically, the problem lies with the nan. So if I would, for example, fill the dataframe with -1 values and afterwards introduce my own values (which will always be positive). Converting to a sparse dataframe with -1 as argument would work?

Comment: its not the ``nan``. In fact that represents a missing value. Its the entirely empty construction on a per-column basis. The routine doesn't deal with this case properly.